# Extjs load combo boxes dynamically using recursive json data

Tags: json, extjs, combobox

I have set of models and a store as given below.

```
Ext.define('User', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            'id', 'name', 'total'],

        hasMany: {
            model: 'Order',
            name: 'orders'
        },

        proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url: 'users.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'users'
            }
        }
    });

    Ext.define('Order', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            'id', 'total'],

        hasMany: {
            model: 'OrderItem',
            name: 'orderItems',
            associationKey: 'order_items'
        },
        belongsTo: 'User'
    });

    Ext.define('OrderItem', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            'id', 'price', 'quantity', 'order_id', 'product_id'],

         belongsTo: ['Order', {model: 'Product', associationKey: 'product'}]
    });

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'User'
    });
```

And below is the json file which I use to load data.

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "id": "123",
            "name": "Ed",
            "orders": [
                {
                    "id": "50",
                    "total": "100",
                    "order_items": [
                        {
                            "id"      : "20",
                            "price"   : "40",
                            "quantity": "2",
                            "product" : {
                                "id": "1000",
                                "name": "MacBook Pro"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "id"      : "21",
                            "price"   : "20",
                            "quantity": "3",
                            "product" : {
                                "id": "1001",
                                "name": "iPhone"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
         {
            "id": "124",
            "name": "Nisha",
            "orders": [
                {
                    "id": "52",
                    "total": "1004",
                    "order_items": [
                        {
                            "id"      : "22",
                            "price"   : "40",
                            "quantity": "23",
                            "product" : {
                                "id": "1002",
                                "name": "Nokia"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "id"      : "23",
                            "price"   : "100",
                            "quantity": "3",
                            "product" : {
                                "id": "1003",
                                "name": "apple"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

I am loading the user IDs to L1_combo_box as below and according to the user ID the user selects from the L1_combo_box, I need to load order_item ids to L2_combo_box .

For example, I load user ids 123, 124 to L1_combo_box and when user selects 123 from L1 combo box, I need  to load 20,21 to L2 combo box. If user selects 124, then I need to load 22,23. 
Below  is the partially completed code. can anyone help me to complete this?

```
var searchFormFieldsetItems =    [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
            combineErrors: true,
            name: 'search_form_fieldset_items',
            msgTarget: 'side',
            fieldLabel: '',
            defaults: {
                hideLabel: true
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'combo',
                name: 'L1_combo_box',
                displayField: 'id',
                valueField: 'id',
                queryMode: 'remote',
                store:store,
                listeners: {
                    change: {
                        fn: function(combo, value) {
                            var store1 = 'users/orders/order_items/';//This line is partially completed
                            L2_combo_box.bindStore(store1);

                        }
                    }
                }

            },{
                xtype: 'combo',
                name: 'L2_combo_box',
                displayField: 'id',
                valueField: 'id'


            }
]
```

}
 ];

Answer (score 1):

For this you need to use [`select`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#event-select) for [`combobox`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html) and inside of `select` event you need to use [`loadData()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-loadData) method of [`store`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.data.Store.html) to adding data in second `combo`.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2coa)**, I have created a demo using your code and put my efforts for showing data in second combo. I hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('User', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
            autoLoad: true,
            alias: 'store.user',
            fields: ["id", "name", "orders"],
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'users.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'users'
                }
            }
        });
        Ext.define('Order', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
            alias: 'store.order',
            field: ["id", "price", "quantity", "product"],
            storeId: 'order'
        });
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'Example Combo',
            bodyPadding: 5,

            defaults: {
                width: 250
            },

            // The fields
            defaultType: 'combo',
            items: [{
                name: 'L1_combo_box',
                displayField: 'id',
                valueField: 'id',
                queryMode: 'local',
                emptyText: 'Select user',
                store: {
                    type: 'user'
                },
                listeners: {
                    select: function (combo, rec) {
                        var L2_combo_box = combo.up('form').getForm().findField('L2_combo_box'),
                            order = rec.get('orders') || [],
                            data = [];
                        //reset combo value
                        L2_combo_box.reset();
                        //If order have multipe data then need use forEach for all data
                        order.forEach(item => {
                            data = data.concat(item.order_items);
                        });
                        //load data in combo store
                        Ext.getStore('order').loadData(data);
                    }
                }
            }, {
                emptyText: 'Select order items',
                name: 'L2_combo_box',
                displayField: 'id',
                valueField: 'id',
                queryMode: 'local',
                store: {
                    type: 'order'
                }
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and I have a small question, Is there a way to bind store to combo box 2 rather than specifying a store inside it? (This is because I have situations where the sub stores have different structures)

Comment: Yes, you can create one another `store` and provide to that combo. After do same functionality. Please see I have updated my answer. I hope [this](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2coa) same as you want.